# I want to get data with and condition but unknown error occured in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

my code is ... i m fetch data with and condition in codeigniter but
some error has occured...  my model is this bellow...

```
 public function hospital_edit($param = null){

     $Hospitals_id = $param;
     $status = 1;
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('wl_hospitals');
     $this->db->where('Hospitals_id', $Hospitals_id);
     $this->db->where('Hospitals_status',$status);
     $result = $this->result();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);exit;

 }
```

Comment: There's no need to add the quote device (`>`) to paragraph text or code - just use the 'code' button for formatting code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly fetch the result without calling `get()` on your query try this

```
$Hospitals_id = $param;
$status = 1;
$query=$this->db
            ->select('*')
            ->from('wl_hospitals')
            ->where('Hospitals_id', $Hospitals_id)
            ->where('Hospitals_status',$status)
            ->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function hospital_edit($param = null){

     $Hospitals_id = $param;
     $status = 1;
     $this->db->where('Hospitals_id', $Hospitals_id);
     $this->db->where('Hospitals_status',$status);
     $query = $this->db->get('wl_hospitals');
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
         $result = $query->result();
    }else{
      echo "No Data";
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public function hospital_edit($param = null){

 $Hospitals_id = $param;
 $status = 1;
 $hospitals = $this->db->get_where('wl_hospitals', array('Hospitals_id' => $Hospitals_id,'Hospitals_status' => $status));
 $result = $hospitals->result();

}
```